Hair guides not following rig pose
I have a hair system set up, and everything works fine, but when the character is posed, the guides do not follow the geometry properly—they appear to float. Turning off interpolation places the guides on the mesh, but when I comb the hair, it moves in the opposite direction. Any ideas of what it could be?

Just a guess: the order of modifiers on the Curves object is probably wrong. Is there a Surface Deform Geometry Nodes modifier? Is it below the Interpolate Hair Curves modifier? Usually, the Surface Deform modifier should be last at the bottom of the stack.

Hi, yes, the surface deform modifier is the last one

Hm. Does the Surface Deform modifier display any errors or warnings? Can you share the file or add a screenshot of the modifiers? If you don't want to share your model or if the file is too big then you can delete everything that is not related to the problem. We need just a demo file that shows the problem. Otherwise, I'm afraid we'll have to keep guessing.
